# visit file from quickfix list without populating oldfiles

Tags: quickfix

I like consulting my `oldfiles` to see what I've been working on recently and to make it easy to find files that are buried deep in various directories. Before I started using the `grep` and `make` commands, the `oldfiles` list only contained files I had intentionally visited, for the most part.

I've recently started using `grep` and other commands that populate the quickfix list, but most of the matches I end up with are not interesting. However, these non-interesting matches end up polluting my `oldfiles` list and limiting its usefulness.

Is it possible to exempt files visited by `cnext` and `cprevious` from being considered visited from the perspective of `oldfiles`.

The ideal solution would be something like an argument to `cnext` or `cprevious` that controls whether the file counts as visited or not for the purposes of `oldfiles`, i.e. `cnext-silent` or something like that if it existed.

```
" begin .vimrc
nnoremap ( :cprevious<cr>                                                                                                            
nnoremap ) :cnext<cr>
" end .vimrc
```

For instance, suppose we have GHC (the Glasgow Haskell Compiler) checked out at `~/git/ghc` and we search for `unwind` on a whim by executing `:grep -r unwind .`.

if we press `)` (rebound in the vimrc), this ends up polluting the oldfiles list with things I didn't actually work on.

```
1: ~/git/ghc/utils/genapply/Main.hs                                                                                
2: ~/git/ghc/rts/StgMiscClosures.cmm
3: ~/git/ghc/rts/StgStartup.cmm
4: ~/git/ghc/rts/win32/veh_excn.c
5: ~/git/ghc/testsuite/tests/typecheck/should_compile/T4524.hs
6: ~/git/ghc/rts/Exception.cmm
7: ~/git/ghc/rts/Libdw.h
8: ~/git/ghc/rts/PrimOps.cmm
9: ~/git/ghc/rts/RaiseAsync.c
10: ~/git/ghc/rts/StgCRun.c
11: ~/git/ghc/compiler/nativeGen/X86/Ppr.hs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few ideas, none of which do what you actually want, but all rely on increased specificity:

1. `:copen`, and be more selective of the matches you select
2. `:grep -r more_specific_pattern more_specific_file_list`—this keeps the results relevant. (A favorite technique of mine is to populate the `:args` list with files I care about—backtick expansion à la

   ```
   :args `ack -f --md`
   ```

   is particularly handy there—and then to `:vimgrep /pattern/ ##` to only search those files.)
3. Try the (new-ish) cfilter plugin with

```
:packadd cfilter
:Cfilter /pattern/
```

---

Actually answering the question: `:help oldfiles` gives

```
                                        *v:oldfiles* *oldfiles-variable*
v:oldfiles      List of file names that is loaded from the |viminfo| file on
                startup.  These are the files that Vim remembers marks for.
                The length of the List is limited by the ' argument of the
                'viminfo' option (default is 100).
                When the |viminfo| file is not used the List is empty.
                Also see |:oldfiles| and |c_#<|.
                The List can be modified, but this has no effect on what is
                stored in the |viminfo| file later.  If you use values other
                than String this will cause trouble.
                {only when compiled with the |+viminfo| feature}
```

So, theoretically, you can do

```
" ~/.vim/autoload/qf.vim
function! qf#silent(direction) abort
  let command = 'c' . get({
        \ 'n': 'next',
        \ 'p': 'prev'},
        \ direction,
        \ 'next')
  exec command
  call remove(v:oldfiles, -1)
endfunction

" ~/.vim/vimrc or whatever
nnoremap ) :call qf#silent('n')<CR>
nnoremap ( :call qf#silent('p')<CR>
```

I don't have much experience defining commands, so there are probably easier ways to do that and get more features out of it.

Also, I'm assuming that `v:oldfiles[-1]` (the last element) is the current buffer, not the most recent. That might be wrong.

I say *theoretically* because, well, it seems like it might have little effect (see the quote).